# Adding a confirmation pop up

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out a way to add a confirmation popup to the following code so that the selected range can't be erased without clicking yes. Any help would be appreciated

```
function reset() {
    var s=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  s.getRange("c5:r25").clearContent();
}
```